# Calculation of accuracy during dead reckoning based for sensor selection

Tags: sensors, dead-reckoning

I am working on a problem in robot tracking, where our main position sensor will be unavailable for up to a second due to its low frequency.
That's why we would need to track its 2D-movements (x&y-axes) during these intervals using an accelerometer. I think the right term for this process is called dead reckoning. In case I lack additional sensors, I probably have to take the double integral of the acceleration...

What I am looking for, is a way to estimate the needed sensor-accuracy to achieve a defined tracking accuracy (say 10mm).
Does maybe a closed form expression exist? Or is there any general work on this topic? (I couldn't find anything)
The only method of doing this that I can think of would be simulating a test trajectory for the sensors and calculate the accuracy. But that would require to run a simulation of every possible sensor candidate...

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, Bobipuegi. This question looks like a duplicate of [another relatively recent question here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/16298/9720), please check out the answer there and *edit this question* to further clarify if/why that isn't sufficient. For your future reference, dead reckoning is using vehicle odometery to estimate location; i.e., using wheel encoders, not an accelerometer. I'm going to put the question *on hold* for now, but again if you still need help just *edit this question* and then flag it for moderator intervention and/or vote to reopen it.